# Populate until value changes perl

Tags: perl, while-loop

I have always wondered this.  How can you fill blanks in columns with the previous data until the next value is reached??  This is a comma delimited file example.

Example data:

```
1,2
,2
,2
,2
3,4
```

Desired output

```
1,2
1,2
1,2
1,2
3,4
```

I know I would use a while loop, but what kind of perl command would be most suitable??  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a state variable to hold the post non-empty value.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(max);

my @lastval;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split ',';

    # Autofill empty fields
    for my $i ( 0 .. max( $#fields, $#lastval ) ) {
        if ( $fields[$i] ne '' ) {
            $lastval[$i] = $fields[$i];
        } else {
            $fields[$i] = $lastval[$i];
        }
    }

    print join( ',', @fields ), "\n";
}

__DATA__
1,2
,2
,2
,2
3,4
```

Output:

```
1,2
1,2
1,2
1,2
3,4
```

Comment: When you know the number of the columns, you can get rid of the `max` thing, and also you can initialize the `@lastval` array to contain default values. And, I think if this solution gets on the first line `,2`, it gives a warning because the `$lastval[0]` is not defined in the first cycle and cannot be printed.

Comment: Yes, it would give a warning if the first line contained a blank value.  However, I believe that it SHOULD do that.

Comment: @miller I can use the max if say I am dealing with a scenario where I'm not sure exactly which columns will need to be auto filled?

Comment: @JDE876 Using `max` just makes your code more dynamic.  If the column length is fixed, you could just rely on the `$#fields` index.  However, since coding the general case is so cheap, one might as well do so.

Comment: Agreed.  Makes it more universal and ambigous. @Miller

Answer (score 1):

In these situations, I would suggest using a variable for each of the columns in which the last defined value will be stored.

Try something like this:

```
my $last_a = 0; # or whatever you want to be the first value
my $last_b = 0;

while(<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($a, $b) = split /,/, 2;

    $last_a = $a unless $a eq '';
    $last_b = $b unless $b eq '';

    print $last_a . "," . $last_b . "\n";
}
```

Optionally, you can adjust the `unless` tests to be more suitable for your problem (e.g. allowing whitespaces, etc.). Moreover, the initial values of `$last_a` and `$last_b` can  be altered to suit your needs.